# How do I access elements across frames?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frames

file1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AIDS (Automated ID System)</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
    id="frames" 
    border="thin" 
    caption="yes" 
    icon="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" 
    showintaskbar="yes" 
    singleinstance="yes" 
    sysmenu="yes" 
    navigable="yes" 
    contextmenu="no" 
    innerborder="no" 
    scroll="auto" 
    scrollflat="yes" 
    selection="yes" 
    windowstate="normal" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function pausecomp(millis) 
    { 
        var date = new Date(); 
        var curDate = null; 
        do { curDate = new Date(); } 
        while(curDate-date < millis); 
    } 

    function getWindowsUserName()
    {
        var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
        var urlToSite = createCustomURL(WinNetwork.UserName);
        var frame = document.getElementById("psyncLink"); 
        frame.onload = function() { 
            frame.onload = null; 
            if (requestingPassword()) { 
                //alert("password button screen");
                passwordButtonScreen();
            } else { 
                alert("direct password required"); 
            } 
        } 
        frame.src = urlToSite;
    }

    function requestingPassword()
    {       
        var btn = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-password.pss");
        if (btn.length == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function passwordButtonScreen()
    {       
        var btn = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-password.pss");       
        btn[0].click();     
    }

    function createCustomURL(userName)
    {
        var customURL = "http://localhost/nph-psf.exe?HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" + userName;
        return customURL;
    }

    function Sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function whichScreen() { 
        var btn = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-password.pss"); 
        if (btn.length == 0) { 
            alert("no button!"); 
            // User is at password screen
            var textField = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("_MYPW");
            textField[0].text = "";
            return; 
        } else { 
            btn[0].click();
            WaitSeconds(5);
            var textField = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("_MYPW");
            textField[0].value = "ios12sdk";
            btn = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-VERIFY");
            btn[0].click();
        }
    }

    var loadOtherFrame = function (text) { 
        getWindowsUserName(); 
        alert(text);
    };

</script>

    </head>     
    <frameset cols="300px, *"> 
        <frame src="leftframe.html" name="topo" id="topo" application="yes" /> 
        <frame src="topo1.htm" name="psyncLink" id="psyncLink" application="yes" /> 
    </frameset>     
</html>
```

leftframe.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>AIDS&nbsp;Assistant</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">

function checkPassword() {
  var validString = /^[a-z](?=[a-z]*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{0,6}[a-z]$/;
  if (validString.test(document.getElementById("newPassword").value)) {
    alert("The password is valid");
    var validate = function () {
        // validate textbox input ...
        // call parent page function
        parent.loadOtherFrame(document.getElementById("newPassword").value);
    };
  } else {
    alert("The new password does NOT meet the requirements. Please try again.");
  }
}



</script>

<body>
    <table width="300px">
        <tr>
            <td>Type Your Old Password</td>
            <td><input id="oldPassword" type="text" maxlength="8" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please type your new password</td>
            <td><input id="newPassword" type="text" maxlength="8" min="8" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input id="checkOldPassword" type="button" title="Check New Password" value="Check New Password" onclick="checkPassword()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Let me clarify what I am doing

1. leftframe.html needs to validate a textbox
2. Once the left frame has been processed. It needs to notify the parent window, file1.html, so it can load the second frame (topo1.htm)

topo.htm doesn't exist so the HTA app loads Page could not be found for that specific frame but it should change when we call function getWindowsUserName() from loadOtherFrame. The loadOtherFrame is called from the leftframe.html file as tjscience indicated.

When I run the HTA, the loadOtherFrame is being called (before the button click on leftframe.html)

Comment: One thing to note is that topo1.htm is not editable by me. It URL redirect's to an external site which I have no control over. SO I need to be able to push the data into the controls in the psyncLink frame

Comment: We've lost your code. Please edit your question, select the code-block and use `{}`-tool of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit to include passing text input along to parent page**

You can call a function in the parent page from the frame when the textbox is validated:

**JS IN Leftframe.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validate = function () {
        // validate textbox input ...
        // call parent page function, passing the text from the input
        parent.loadOtherFrame(text);
    };
</script>
```

**JS in file1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loadOtherFrame = function (text) {
        // load other frame here ...
    };
</script>
```

Comment: how about the text input? how do I pass that data along?

Comment: Basically, you would just pass it as an argument to the function.  See my edits.

Comment: does the var need to be nested in a function or just anywhere within the <script tags?

Comment: What var are you referring to?  If you are confused on the function syntax, var loadOtherFrame = function (text) {...} is pretty much the same as function loadOtherFrame(text) {...}

Comment: I added that var into the file1.html but it's always executing (even without the call from leftframe.html)

Comment: Could you post your code where you added it? The function should not execute unless called.

Comment: From your revised code, this is happening because you are calling btn[0].click(); in the frame load handler. Although, the function still should not execute because, in checkPassword() you are not executing the function that has parent.loadOtherFrame in it, you are only assigning this function to the variable validate.

Comment: Whats a frame load handler? I am still new to JS but learning everyday.

Comment: The portion of your code in file1.html where you have frame.onload = function() { ...  This will be executed when the frame is loaded.

Comment: That occurs even if it's in a function that is not called? How do I fix this so we can get the expected behavior?

Comment: Setting frame.onload = function () {...} is the same as saying, "after the frame is loaded, execute the function stored in frame.onload". I'm really not sure how else to explain it. I think that the best thing to do at this point would be to take a step back and learn the basics of javascript before you delve into more complicated code such as this.

Comment: I understand what the frame.onload does but the reason for that code was to make the frame wait for customURL to load. So is there another way to make it wait for customURL to load? We never even made any function calls to cause it to load

Comment: is there an alternative way for me to avoid using onload for the frame?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12890/discussion-between-cocoa-dev-and-tjscience)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `frameset`is not in the `frame` already. You can access all frames via `top.window.frame_name` from any `frame` or `top.window` itself.

```
form_in_psyncLink=top.window.psyncLink.document.getElementById('form_id');
```

---

**EDIT**

If this external page is not in the same domain, you can't acces it's content by regular means. Read more about [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). (AFAIK HTA doesn't change this behavior.)

My example above gives you a reference to the `psyncLink`, naturally you'll use it in your validating script to access elements in `psyncLink` to "paste" data. (which in this case maybe impossible due to the cross-domained pages)

Comment: I am confused about 1 thing. In my leftframe.html I have a button that validates the input into the textbox. How will the parent frame know when the button is pressed?

Comment: The current HTA app can click buttons in the frame (psyncLink), I can input text from the parent frame. But I am trying to input text from the leftframe page (instead of the parent)

Comment: Now I'm confused... Your'e giving a value to a text-input in `psyncLink` from `top.window`? Then programmatically clicking a `Validate` button from `top.window`? And now you want to copy the validated value in `psyncLink` to a text-input in `topo`? And all this should be done with script in `top.window`?